# EntityManagerFactory Returns Null

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm

I have the following service class to return an int using an `EntityManager` query() method.

```
public class QueryService {
   @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider")
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  public int getCount(User user) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    int count;
    Query qry = em.createQuery(
            "select count(*) from User where managerId=? AND address=?");
    qry.setParameter(1, user.getManagerId());
    qry.setParameter(2, user.getAddress());
    try {
        count = ((Long) qry.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        count = 0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

However `emf` returns null and my query cannot be run. I am using the `EntityManagerFactory` the exact same way on my `@Controller` methods and this works properly. Perhaps I don't know enough about how the EMF works yet, does anyone have any ideas?

My package structure

```
src
    com.mysite.controllers
    com.mysite.repositories
    com.mysite.services
        -QueryService.java
```

**UPDATE:** I am using Java Config for my project setup (no .xml) - including my EMF Configuration

```
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.mysite" });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setPersistenceProvider(vendorAdapter.getPersistenceProvider());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider");
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }
```

Comment: You have annotated your QueryService class properly and the package is in the  context:scan basepackage?

Comment: add your spring configuration file

Comment: Which versions of spring-orm and hibernate-entitymanager are you using? And why are you setting `PersistenceProvider` explicity? It supouse that the `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` provides to the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Answer (score 0):

Configure your JPA Provider (using `persistence.xml`, `hibernate.cfg.xml` or spring configuration, or annotations) and Spring.

If you have configured JPA and Spring, could you add these files to your question, so we can see the contents?

Comment: Included my Entity Manager Factory config